# How to connect dust port from Dewalt table saw to Shop Vac?

Tags: table-saw, dust-collection, shop-vac

I recently bought a Dewalt Model #DWE7491RS table saw and it has a 2-1/2" dust port (2-1/4" inner diameter).  I also have a small size Shop Vac that has a hose with a plastic nozzle at the end that has a 1-1/4" diameter (1" inner diameter).

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to connect the table saw dust port to my shop vac.  I have looked and looked and looked online and I can't find any adapters that will fit.  I have found some 2-1/2" hard plastic adapters, but they are *exactly* the same size as the table saw dust port so they don't work.  I either need something a little larger to fit over the table saw dust port or a little smaller to fit inside it.  This is driving me crazy.  I feel like with a popular table saw like the Dewalt this shouldn't be that difficult.  Anyone have any ideas for how I can accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: I don't want to be a buzzkill, but you run the risk of clogging your little hose pretty quickly. Look into the cyclone bucket idea: it still won't be great, but will improve your life a little...

Comment: Yeah I was wondering if I need to buy a larger shop vac.

Comment: You (probably) don't need to buy anything new. Always repurpose what you have first. The recommendation is to make a nearly free cyclone bucket and put that in the line before the vacuum. Instructions for DIY cyclone buckets are ubiquitous on the internet, and there may even be one here. In fact, that would make an excellent Question if you have a particular free bucket and want to see how others might put it to use as a separator (and one does not already exist).

Comment: Also, you might want to check out https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/10582/5572 My guess is that DeWalt is in the process of not-quite-voluntarily replacing these models because they might pose a risk of flinging blades off the arbor.

Comment: @jdv is DeWalt actually recalling them? If you've got a link, it would improve that otherwise already excellent answer.

Comment: No, but I think if you complain hard enough they replace or refund it? That was what I understood from the last report we saw here.

Comment: Related: https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/4700/5572

Comment: could you please post the picture or link of the product you bought? I'm stuck on the same problem. In addition, what about the upper dust port on the safeguard? Do you use a y-splitter to collect dust from both ports?

Comment: Lowe’s sells a hose kit that includes the exact adapter you need. I, too, struggled to figure out how it could be so difficult.

Comment: You can simply get a 3d printed adapter off of Etsy. I got one for $13 and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would use this type of adapter which you can obtain from any of the big box stores in the shop vac department.  This adapter kit handles 2 1/2, 1 7/8, and 1/1/4 hoses.

[This link for adapter](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RIDGID-Hose-and-Accessory-Adapter-Kit-for-RIDGID-Wet-Dry-Shop-Vacuums-VT1755/202077239)

Pictures from Home Depot:

[image: 1]

[image]

If you don't want to use the 2 1/2" hose first, you can attach the adapter with this rubber coupling.  If it is a tight fit, just heat the rubber first with a hot air gun.  Do one end at a time, wear gloves

Picture from Rockler website:

[image]

Comment: That one won’t work. The problem is that the 2-1/2” adapter is EXACTLY the same size as the dust port. It’s not big enough to fit over the dust port and it’s too big to slide in to the dust port

Comment: You use the 2 1/2 Hose to connect first to the DeWalt, then use the adapter to reduce down to the size you want.

Comment: @CoreyBurnett Starting at the saw, connect part #3, then #1, then #2, then the shop vac hose.

Comment: In short, all of these fittings are somewhat standard, and all you need is the right male-female fittings.

Comment: For that rubber fitting, stop by the plumbing section of your local big-box home center and look for (or ask about) a "Fernco". It's the same exact thing, designed for plumbing purposes. They probably sell a lot more of them, so the price _might_ be lower. Do be sure to check that a 2-1/2" Fernco will properly fit a 2-1/2" vac hose. Pipe wall thicknesses are different, so OD may be different for the same ID.

Comment: I'm too late for the OP, but I had a similar situation where I was looking to connect my large 4" dust collector hose to a 1-1/2" OD connection on my spindle sander. I already have a large conical shaped adapter that reduces the 4" to 2-1/2" (2-1/4" ID). I found an OpenSCAD file on Thingiverse and edited it for my relevant diameters and 3D printed it at my local library. It works! I didn't want the heavy 4" hose hanging directly off the small connection on the spindle sander so I put a couple feet of hose on it. It decouples the sander from the heavy hose and allows for better positioning too.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to some of the comments I figured out the solution. I was thinking about this wrong! I was looking for a hard plastic adapter that would go right on the dust port of the table saw. After reading the comments I realized what I needed to do was attach a hose to the dust port FIRST, then attach adapters to the hose. Today I bought a universal kit that included 2-1/2" hose and some adapters and it worked perfectly! Thanks so much. I knew I was just not thinking about this the right way.

[image]

Comment: This is what I stated in my comment to use the hose first.

Comment: @Programmer66: "Thanks to some of the comments I figured out the solution." so I'd guess he read your comment, too. ;) Also, I'm not sure this would have worked had he not picked up a 2nd section of hose, he'd have just translated the problem to the shop vac end of the setup.

Answer (score 1):

ABS fittings will also do the trick. Parts needed are:
1 1/2 hub x hub coupling
1 1/2 - 1 1/4 spigot x slip joint trap adapter
Painters tape (optional)

See picture. [image][image]

Comment: How "optional" is that painer's tape?

Comment: Without the painters tape the coupling wiggles a little.  I wrapped painters tape 5-6 times around it for a tight fit.

Comment: Hockey tape can also give you the needed gap filling for ad hoc slip connectors. My shop vacuum agrees.

Answer (score -1):

Your best option is an intercooler/turbo hose adapter from 2.5in to 1.75". Stays flexible all the time even in extreme cold and doesn't need clamps. Cost around $10. Amazon, eBay or Auto-stores have them

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00XKDEJBK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00XKDEJBK)

Comment: "Currently unavailable" lol

Comment: What about this makes it the "best" bet?

Comment: Also wondering why remaining flexible in extreme cold is a bonus. Most woodworkers go inside if it's extremely cold outside. Or, they heat the shop.