# Dimensions of DeWalt Table saw DWV9470 Hose

Tags: table-saw, dust-collection

I have a Record Power Dust Extractor with a 4" inlet pipe.

https://www.recordpower.co.uk/product/55l-1000w-medium-extractor-4-inlet#.Y3bGMS-l2L0

Looking to hook this up to a DWE7485 table saw using the DeWalt DWV9470-XJ AirLock Y Splitter Hose Kit

https://www.dewalt.co.uk/product/dwv9470-xj/airlock-y-splitter-hose-kit

Does anyone happen to know the dimensions of the DeWalt Y Splitter hose kit? I need to know what I need to step down to from the 4" outlet.

There's no mention of pipe dimensions on the DeWalt site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the listings of a couple of vendors — e.g. [Toolnation](https://www.toolnation.com/dewalt-accessories-dwv9470-xj-airlock-y-splitter-dust-extraction-set.html) — the diameter is **32mm**.

> - Y-adapter
> - 2 x flexible suction hoses (each diameter 32 mm / 1.4 m)
> - 2x AirLock-adapter (DWV9000-XJ)

---

As this might help for similar searches, typing "DeWalt DWV9470-XJ diameter" into Google gave results on the first page.

Like on the DeWalt site numerous other listings don't give the diameter, including the ones on Toolstop and Amazon.co.uk, although the latter does go to the trouble of listing the *exact* dimensions of the box it comes in (‎44.96 x 34.8 x 12.7 cm) and that it's 130.41g..... those last .6mm and .41 grams, so important :-|

But anyway, you can get to it by another route: what it's compatible with. Even the Amazon listing for the DWV9000 Universal Connector includes:

> - Universal allows for quick, easy and durable connection between **1 1/4"** Vacuum hose and various DW tools & shrouds

1 1/4" = 31.75mm.

Note that there's no way to know which direction the rounding occurs, in case this might affect fit to any third-party adaptors you end up using.

Comment: After purchasing the DeWalt DWV9470-XJ AirLock Y Splitter Hose Kit.  I can confirm it only fits one of the dust ports on a DWE7485 table saw.  The lower port will need a tapered connector to bring the two together.

Comment: FWIW the various responses to [this other Question](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/13053/how-to-connect-dust-port-from-dewalt-table-saw-to-shop-vac) might be of some help.